# Configure webpack to ignore define statement

Tags: javascript, requirejs, require, amd, webpack

How can I confgure webpack to ignore amd 'define' statements in the file, like I can do it with 'require' with externals option?

Answer (score 1):

as stated here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3017#issuecomment-285954512

you could do:

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    { parser: { amd: false } }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Officially it is [recommended](https://github.com/webpack/imports-loader#disable-amd) to set `define` to false with `imports-loader`.

```
loaders: [
  { test: /\.js/, loader: 'imports?define=>false'}
]
```

But it is useful only if `define` is called in UMD style - something like this:

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
  define([], factory)
}
```

If you can change code that calls `define` and there is no UMD's `if` this is what worked for me:

```
var define = window['infor']; // keep webpack out of way

// use define from global scope (requirejs or other used loader) as needed
define('mymodule', ['dep1'], function (dep1) {
  return {}
});
```